# How to select the record with minimum value from table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have table BIDS, which contains a lot of columns and rows but I only want to select a row which contains lowest BIDPRICE.

```
Select min(Cast(Bids.BidPrice as INT)), BidBidderName from bids BidBidderName
```

but it throws error

> Column 'bids.BidBidderName' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function

When I put BidderName in Group by then it shows all records but I only want record which contains lowest bid price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subquery:

```
Select BidPrice, BidBidderName from bids 
where Bids.BidPrice in (Select  min(Cast(b.BidPrice as INT)) from bids b)
```

Or `INNER JOIN`:

```
Select b1.BidPrice, b1.BidBidderName from bids b1
inner join (select Min(BidPrice) BidPrice from @bids) as b2 on b.BidPrice = b2.BidPrice
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option that will get just the row with the lowest price.

```
Select top 1 BidPrice
    , BidBidderName 
from bids
order by Cast(BidPrice as INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want rows that have the lowest bid price one solution is to use a subquery to find the minimum price like this:

```
Select  BidPrice, BidBidderName 
from bids 
where BidPrice = (select min(Cast(BidPrice as INT)) from bids)
```

If the BidPrice is either money or a numeric type (which it most likely should be) the cast to int is not necessary.

If you do

```
Select Min(BidPrice) BidPrice, BidBidderName 
from bids 
group by BidBibberName
```

you would instead get the lowest bid for every bidder.

Comment: The last one gives many records which I don't want, I want single record with lowest price

Comment: @Covert Yes, I only included the second query to show the difference. The first one should be what you want. It will give you the rows matching the lowest price.

Comment: @Covert So did the first query work and give the desired output, or was it something else you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

try:

> Row_Number()

```
;with cte1 
as
(
select BidderName ,BidPrice,Row_Number() Over(order by price asc) as rn from bids
)
select * from cte1 where rn=1;
```

Or

> Min(BidPrice) Over(PARTITION BY BidderName order by price asc)

```
select top 1 BidderName ,Min(BidPrice) Over(PARTITION BY BidderName order by price asc) as minBidPrice from bids
```